# JPA - disable inheritance on Subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, jpa, eclipselink

My Class "Resource_Image" is a subclass of Resource and all things work as expected, but in my Database both tables containing the column "STRUCTURE". Why? 
Using setRs on an Resource_Image instance is setting Resource_Structure on superclass, but why i'm having the column "STRUCTURE" on Table "res_images" too, it doesn't make sense?
See the Code at the bottom. Any Ideas?

```
@Entity
@Table(name="res")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Resource {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "STRUCTURE",nullable=false)
    private Resource_Structure rs;

    //getter and setter for rs
    public final void setRs(Resource_Structure rs) {
        this.rs = rs;
    }
    //...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="res_images")
public class Resource_Image extends Resource
{
    @Column(name = "WIDTH",nullable=false)
    private int width;

    @Column(name = "HEIGHT",nullable=false)
    private int height;

    //NO getter and setter for rs
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are those your complete class files?

From the code, STRUCTURE should only be defined in the res table.  Are you using auto DDL generation and seeing it created in res_images?  Do you have any relationships to Resource_Image that uses that column?  When you persist and object, does it try to insert into that column?

Comment: This is only an excerpt of the involved properties/classes. STRUCTURE and the setters/getters were only defined in res table. But it is shown in the database on res and res_image (yes i'm using auto DLL generation). After persist, this column is null in the res_image table and set correctly in the res table. So the STRUCTURE-column in res_image is complete useless but available. In my opinion the column is created because of the possibility to overwrite that property, is there a way to tell JPA "this property only exists in superclass an could not be overwritten"?